# Postgresql - select corresponding lead column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can find the ***lead status date*** for each row by using

```
select lead(status_date) OVER(ORDER BY dept_id, status_date, id) as "lead_date" from my_table
```

How do I get the corresponding the ***lead status***, in the same order as the ***lead status date***?

```
id, dept_id, status, statud_date
---------------------------------
1   001      OPEN    1/1/2017
2   001      ACTIVE  2/2/2017
3   002      CLOSED  1/15/2017
```

Comment: use `lead` on `status` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the argument to `lead()`:

```
select lead(status_date) OVER (ORDER BY dept_id, status_date, id) as next_status_date,
       lead(status) OVER (ORDER BY dept_id, status_date, id) as next_status      
from my_table;
```

Normally, I would want the status *by department* so I would think this is what you want:

```
select lead(status_date) OVER (partition by dept_id ORDER BY status_date, id) as next_status_date,
       lead(status) OVER (partition by dept_id ORDER BY status_date, id) as next_status      
from my_table;
```

When you have multiple window specifications using the same clause, you can specify the clause once:

```
select lead(status_date) over w as next_status_date,
       lead(status) over w as next_status      
from my_table
window w as (partition by dept_id order by status_date, id) ;
```